# I created a table in R. I want to combine its counts. How?

Tags: r, if-statement

I created the following frequency table for samples per year.

```
1975  1976  1980   1995  2017  2018 
2      67    44    126   64    133
```

I need to merge the counts of some years together and keep others as is.

```
Eighties   Nineties  Two Thousands
2+67+44      126        64+133
```

I tried creating a new variable with a nested if statement. I have never used this function before so this is me mimicking Excel.

```
a$decade -> ifelse(a$year=1975 | a$year=1976 |a$year=1980,"Eighties",
                   ifelse(a$year=1995,"Ninties",
                          ifelse(a$year=2017|a$year=2018,"Two Thousands","Error")))
```

But this is the error I get when I run this code:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "a$decade -> ifelse(a$year="E
>                    ifelse(a$year=1995,"Ninties",
Error: unexpected '=' in "                   ifelse(a$year="
>                           ifelse(a$year=2017|a$year=2018,"Two Thousands","Error")))
Error: unexpected '=' in "                          ifelse(a$year="
>
```

I attempted this code next but there is an error.

```
a$decade <- ifelse(a$year %in% (c("1975", "1976","1980"), "Eighties", (c("1995"),"Nineties"),(c("2017", "2018"),"2000s"))
```

**I am adding a note here that this code will be replicated for other variables such as dividing months into seasons, or days into weekdays/weekends or sampling locations to North/South/East/West so I am hoping for versatile suggestions.**

I attempted the following code

```
a %>%
  mutate(decade = case_when(
    year %in% c(1975, 1976, 1980) ~ "Eighties",
    year == 1995 ~ "Nineties",
    year %in% c(2017, 2018) ~ "Two Thousands"
  )) %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But I got this error

Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `count`.
i `count = sum(count)`.
x invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
i The error occurred in group 1: decade = "Eighties".

Comment: If you want to do an 'equality' comparison, use a double equal sign: ==, e.g. ifelse(x==1, …)

Comment: If there are more than one element, use `%in%` i.e. `ifelse(a$year %in% c(2017, 2018), ...`

Comment: @akrun I just amended my question to try this method. I used it for a simpler comparison and I don't know how to expand it

Comment: Do you have a named  vector or table object?

Comment: @akrun I don't know what the question means. I am very new to R.

Comment: Can you show the output of `str(a)` or `class(a)`

Comment: > class(a)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(a$year)
[1] "numeric"

Comment: So you have two columns?  what is the second column name

Comment: This is a very large database with 15 columns so far and around 400 samples. I ran the class function for a as the dataframe and year as the variable I am trying to have a frequency table to.

Answer (score 1):

Using case_when() from tidyverse family:

```
# your data
df<-data.frame(
           year = c(1975, 1976, 1980, 1995, 2017, 2018),
           count = c(2, 67, 44, 126, 64, 133)
       )


  
  # combining counts 


library(tidyverse)

    df %>%
      mutate(decade = case_when(
        year %in% c(1975, 1976, 1980) ~ "Eighties",
        year == 1995 ~ "Nineties",
        year %in% c(2017, 2018) ~ "Two Thousands"
      )) %>%
      group_by(decade) %>%
      summarize(count = sum(count)) %>%
      ungroup()
```

output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  decade        count
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 Eighties        113
2 Nineties        126
3 Two Thousands   197
```

Comment: I tried this code to have year_group called decade instead. and I got the following error: Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `count`.
i `count = sum(count)`.
x invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
i The error occurred in group 1: decade = "Eighties".

Comment: I replaced year_group with decade in my answer. you must install and run 'tidyverse' package.

Comment: Thank you. The error persists. I have made edits to the question to showcase what's been done so far.

Comment: try to rename count  to, for example : summarize(total_count = sum(count))

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  mutate(year_group = cut(floor(year/10) * 10, breaks = c(-Inf, 1981, 
    2000, Inf), labels = c("Eighties", "Nineties", "Two Thousands"))) %>% 
  reframe(value = sum(value), .by = year_group)
```

-output

```
    year_group value
1      Eighties   113
2      Nineties   126
3 Two Thousands   197
```

#### data

```
a <- structure(list(year = c(1975, 1976, 1980, 1995, 2017, 2018), 
    value = c(2, 67, 44, 126, 64, 133)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I got the following error for this Error in reframe(., value = sum(value), .by = decade) : 
  could not find function "reframe" . Currently, I have the following packages active library(lubridate) 
library(knitr) 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that came to my mind was

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  year = c(1975, 1976, 1980, 1995, 2017, 2018),
  count = c(2, 67, 44, 126, 64, 133)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    decade = 10 * (year %/% 10),
    decade = ifelse(decade == 1970, 1980, decade)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(decade) %>% 
  summarize(count = sum(count))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  decade count
   <dbl> <dbl>
1   1980   113
2   1990   126
3   2010   197
```

Comment: Currently class(a$year) is numeric. I got this error Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function". Do I need to change the class of year for this work? And if yes, to what? Also, I need to replicate this code for other variable divisions. Is there a more generic way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a variation of my original code and this is what ultimately worked

```
a$period<-NA 
a$period[a$year==1975 | a$year==1976 | a$year==1980]<- "Before 1980"
a$period[a$year==1995]<- "1981-2010"
a$period[a$year==2017 | a$year==2018]<- "After 2010"
```